# Does anyone recognise this kind of public key?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

For an application I want to write, the webservice gives me this public key, with which I have to encrypt the password for signing in. But I don't know what kind of encryption this might be. Is this recognisable? Is it possible to tell what this is or do I have to find it out my own by sniffing into the JavaScript (of the web GUI) which handles this key?

Here it is:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDN+SsAsYvIstaZ\/SYUNv7wvr+a
Ajkc28XxuKWpCbqFQS+EWeYpbuBB88iJU98yFjsFMh5BLbXhEX+2JmrC0DWd6o3r
1ILhNL27KmXo6Dh+2y0b9l3YXtmwiA1ThZEQun4Z1rUBPMF43DF805keLIsASFpj
nzc6zWw+jYCX7PTasQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The fact that there is `PUBLIC KEY`, indicates this is asymmetric encryption. But there are lots of it. Here is a list, taken from Wikipedia of asymmetric encryption methods:

> Benaloh · Blum–Goldwasser · Cayley–Purser · CEILIDH · Cramer–Shoup ·
>   Damgård–Jurik · DH · DSA · EPOC · ECDH · ECDSA · EKE · ElGamal
>   (encryption · signature scheme) · GMR · Goldwasser–Micali · HFE · IES
>   · Lamport · McEliece · Merkle–Hellman · MQV · Naccache–Stern ·
>   NTRUEncrypt · NTRUSign · Paillier · Rabin · RSA · Okamoto–Uchiyama ·
>   Schnorr · Schmidt–Samoa · SPEKE · SRP · STS · Three-pass protocol ·
>   XTR

RSA is the only one I know by it's name. Is that the most common one?

Thanks you very much for the help.

Comment: Looks like a certificate signing request (CSR) for an SSL cert.  It's not though -- http://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html

Comment: openssl can't seem to decode it (tries in rsa, dsa mode with `-pubin` with all `-inform` options, as well as req and with gpg

Comment: The key contains a backslash in the first line which makes this a typo question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a 1024-bit RSA public key in PEM format with one character mangled in the first line:

```
Public-Key: (1024 bit)
Modulus:
 00:cd:f9:2b:00:b1:8b:c8:b2:d6:99:fd:26:14:36:
 fe:f0:be:bf:9a:02:39:1c:db:c5:f1:b8:a5:a9:09:
 ba:85:41:2f:84:59:e6:29:6e:e0:41:f3:c8:89:53:
 df:32:16:3b:05:32:1e:41:2d:b5:e1:11:7f:b6:26:
 6a:c2:d0:35:9d:ea:8d:eb:d4:82:e1:34:bd:bb:2a:
 65:e8:e8:38:7e:db:2d:1b:f6:5d:d8:5e:d9:b0:88:
 0d:53:85:91:10:ba:7e:19:d6:b5:01:3c:c1:78:dc:
 31:7c:d3:99:1e:2c:8b:00:48:5a:63:9f:37:3a:cd:
 6c:3e:8d:80:97:ec:f4:da:b1
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

Comment: Are you very sure about this? If so, you are amazing!

Comment: I'll happily +1 this if you can tell us how you knew that?

Comment: Did you write a script to try various one-character substitutions until you found this? :)

Comment: Look at the first line. You'll see it's one character longer than the others. Backslash is not a legal base64 character.

Comment: This truly is a nice answer